# close Sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

i am trying to close data base but it give me error.

```
private SQLiteDatabase sq;

//cardDatabase name of my class.

public void close_DB(){

CardDatabase data_open=new CardDatabase(MyContext);

sq.close();

data_open.close_DB();

}
```

> 03-02 09:13:03.841: D/java.lang.NullPointerException(2447):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-02 09:13:03.841:
>   D/java.lang.NullPointerException(2447): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-02 09:13:03.841: D/java.lang.NullPointerException(2447):   at
>   com.livecards.beta.CardDatabase.close_DB(CardDatabase.java:52)

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `sq` variable is null.

You can add null check before close the database.

```
if(sq != null)
   sq.close();
```